# When does the 24 hour cancellation period start?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations

I currently have a booking (American Airlines) stuck in limbo. There was an unspecified error message after the booking, there is a PNR and the booking is visible online, but the ticket has not been issued and any attempt to do something (changing, cancelling) results in an error message.

I can book something else instead, but I want to make sure I'm not ending up with two tickets.

The original booking comes with 24-hour free cancellation. When does that period actually start ? Does it start when the PNR gets generated or when the actual ticket is getting issued (and you get a real confirmation email).

Comment: The last time I had a similar booking problem (PNR issued but no ticket) the booking 'cancelled' itself (ak just disappeared from my account) in a couple of hours and no payment was taken. Leaving me to safely book again. If it's taking long enough to resolve that the 24 hours is in question I'd try calling customer services.

Comment: @etmuse:  I did indeed called customer service. After a LOOONG wait, it turned out the agent's headset was broken and I couldn't understand what they are saying. It sounded though like they wanted me to just wait.

Comment: it would be wise to assume the airline will attempt to interpret the terms in the manner least favorable to you and move to cancel as quickly as possible if you want to do so

Comment: @mlc: I'd be fine cancelling  but how ? Web site produces a "bad request" error, chat can't do cancellation and phone wait times are astronomically long.

Comment: @Hilmar "phone wait times are astronomically long." that's why I am always annoyed when some people here comment "have you tried to call the customer service??" on some questions. If I cared about that community, I'd put a poll as a Meta question on the longest waiting times, with screenshots of call log for proof.